# Bank Card Generator Code

Tags: java, object-oriented, recursion

This program is used to create a random bank card number. Card number is created using account type and client location for the first eight digits and the remaining 8 digits are completely random. I'm new to this site, but I believe it's just for code review to get opinions on code. If i'm incorrect please let me know and I can take this down. Otherwise, feel free to give me feedback. Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static ArrayList<String> storedCardNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        menu();

    }

    //create menu for checking list of cards or creating a new card
    public static void menu(){
        //used to check if client wants to exit program
        boolean exit = false;

        System.out.println("___________________\n" +
                "Welcome to our bank!\n" + "Choose an option below: \n" +
                "1. Create new bank card.\n" +
                "2. Check existing cards.\n" +
                "3. Exit.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        if(choice == 1) {
            createNewCard();
        } else if(choice == 2){
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println("There are " + storedCardNumbers.size() + " cards in the system");
            for (int i = 0; i < storedCardNumbers.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(storedCardNumbers.get(i).toString());
            }
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
        } else if(choice == 3) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for coming in!");
            exit = true;
        } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect choice.\n" +
                        "Please choose a valid option: ");
                menu();
            }

        if(exit == false) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to do anything else?");
            menu();
        } else {

        }
        }


    //create new bank card with user params
    public static String createNewCard() {
//        String accountType = setCardAccountType();
//        String location = setAccountLocation();
        String cardNumber = getCardNumber(setCardAccountType(),setAccountLocation());
        System.out.println("New card successfully created.\n" +
                "Your new bank card number is: \n" +
                cardNumber);
        storedCardNumbers.add(cardNumber);
        return cardNumber;
        }

        public static String setAccountLocation() {

            String location = "other";

            System.out.println("What is your location?\n" +
                    "1. US East\n" +
                    "2. US West\n" +
                    "3. Hawaii\n" +
                    "4. Alaska\n" +
                    "5. Other.");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                location.equalsIgnoreCase("useast");
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                location.equalsIgnoreCase("uswest");
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                location.equalsIgnoreCase("alaska");
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                location.equalsIgnoreCase("hawaii");
            } else if(choice == 5) {
                location.equalsIgnoreCase("other");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Entered invalid selection.\n" +
                        "Please enter valid selection.");
                setCardAccountType();
            }

            return location;
        }

        //set the card account type for the creatNewCard method to use
        public static String setCardAccountType() {

            String accountType = "other";

            System.out.println("Which type of account do you have?\n" +
                    "1. Checking.\n" +
                    "2. Savings.\n" +
                    "3. Credit.\n" +
                    "4. Other.\n" +
                    "Enter corresponding digit: ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("checking");
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("savings");
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("credit");
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("other");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Entered invalid selection.\n" +
                        "Please enter valid selection.");
                setCardAccountType();
            }

            return accountType;
        }

    //create random number for card
    public static int getRandom(int min, int max) {
        return (int) (Math.random()*(max - min)) + min;
    }

    public static String getCardNumber(String accountType, String location) {
        //first set of four
        int accountKeySet;
        //second set of four
        int locationKeySet;
        //third set of four
        int lastEightFirst;
        //fourth set of four
        int lastEightSecond;

        //assign a value to each account type
        if(accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("checking")) {
            accountKeySet = 4400;
        } else if(accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("savings")) {
            accountKeySet = 4300;
        } else if(accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("credit")) {
            accountKeySet = 4200;
        } else {
            accountKeySet = 4000;
        }


        //Assign a value to each location of client
        if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("useast")) {
            locationKeySet = 1011;
        } else if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("uswest")) {
            locationKeySet = 2011;
        } else if (location.equalsIgnoreCase("Alaska")) {
            locationKeySet = 3011;
        } else if (location.equalsIgnoreCase("hawaii")) {
            locationKeySet = 4011;
        } else {
            locationKeySet = 1022;
        }

        //create a randomized number for last of card number
        lastEightFirst = getRandom(1000,9999);
        lastEightSecond = getRandom(1000,9999);

        //construct card number
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
        key.append(accountKeySet);
        key.append(" ");
        key.append(locationKeySet);
        key.append(" ");
        key.append(lastEightFirst);
        key.append(" ");
        key.append(lastEightSecond);
        return key.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Nicholas and welcome to code review.

A few things that I noticed in your code:

- The indentation isn't consistent. The closing bracket of `menu` isn't where it should be. The whole `setAccountLocation` method is one tab to far right. The readability of the code would be better if you'd fix that. In Eclipse, you can press Ctrl + Shift + F to automatically fix the indentation
- In my experience, opening multiple `Scanner`s yields problems. I'd recommend to open only one `Scanner` in your main method and then use it in your other methods
- In `setAccountLocation`, you use `location.equalsIgnoreCase` several times. That does nothing. I think you wanted to assign the strings to the location variable, so you can simply write `location = "useast";` etc.
- Same for the account types in `setAccountType`.
- `accountType` and `location` are never entered by a user, so you don't need `equalsIgnoreCase`, but you can simply use `equals`.
- I'd recommend to not pass `accountType` and `location` as strings, but to create enums for them.
- in `menu`, you have the line `System.out.println(storedCardNumbers.get(i).toString());`. You don't need the `toString`, because it already is a string. Also the `println` method implicitly calls the `toString` method of every Object that you pass.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response! Yea the indentation is fine on intellij so I think it was just when it was copied over. You review was very helpful thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. There's one more thing that I saw, but forgot to mention. Whenever the user entered an option in the main menu, you call `menu` recursive. That may not become a problem in a small program like this, but in bigger projects you may run out of memory. Also you have to enter 3 for exit multiple times if you chose an incorrect option. You could use a `while (!exit)` loop instead. (PS: Maybe a silly question, but why did you accept the least helpful answer?)

Comment: It's been a long time since I've been on here so I really forgot how it works and forgot that you accept only one answer. I accepted yours now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

### Always use the base class / interface in the left part of the variable when possible

By setting the `java.util.List` interface in the variable part, this could make the code more refactorable in the future, since you could easily change the list type without changing everything (inheritance).

**Before**

```java
private static ArrayList<String> storedCardNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**After**

```java
private static List<String> storedCardNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

### Replace the `for` loop with an enhanced 'for' loop

In your code, you don’t actually need the index provided by the loop, you can the enhanced version.

**Before**

```java
for (int i = 0; i < storedCardNumbers.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(storedCardNumbers.get(i).toString());
}
```

**After**

```java
for (String storedCardNumber : storedCardNumbers) {
   System.out.println(storedCardNumber);
}
```

Also, you can remove the `.toString()` since it's already a String.

### Remove the dead code

In your code, you have multiple places where the code is dead (does nothing) and can be removed.

```java
if (choice == 1) {
   location.equalsIgnoreCase("useast");
} else if (choice == 2) {
   location.equalsIgnoreCase("uswest");
} else if (choice == 3) {
   location.equalsIgnoreCase("alaska");
} else if (choice == 4) {
   location.equalsIgnoreCase("hawaii");
} else if (choice == 5) {
   location.equalsIgnoreCase("other");
} else {
   System.out.println("Entered invalid selection.\n" +
                      "Please enter valid selection.");
   setCardAccountType();
}
```

For an example, the `location.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` is dead code in all cases, even if the condition is met (`choice >= 1 5 && choice <= 5`), the code won’t do anything; you have two similar case like this one.

### Simplify the boolean conditions.

Instead of having `exit == false`, you can simplify to `!exit`; also I suggest that you remove the empty `else` under this condition.

### Generating random values

This is only a suggestion, but you can also use the `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom#nextInt` method to generate a random number in a defined range (inclusive in this case) with java 7+.

```java
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100);
```

You can read an excellent post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

> This program is used to create a random bank card number. Card number is created using account type and client location for the first eight digits and the remaining 8 digits are completely random.

This isn't a critique of the coding per se, but of the requirements gathering.  Bank cards do not allow for a fully random last eight characters.  Because the sixteenth character is a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).  So you should generate seven random digits, not eight.  Then calculate the last digit from the first fifteen.